# QGIS: Landover Analysis Dialog Box Too Small

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, land-cover, dialog

When I open the Landcover Analysis plugin within QGIS, the information in the dialog box is overlapping and doesn't fit the window. Even if I increase the size of the dialog box. It makes it pretty much impossible to use.

[image: Dialog box issue]

Comment: Which QGIS version?  What operating system? What monitor pixel resolution is your computer using?

Comment: QGIS: 3.10.6 A Coruña (though have tried other versions and still occurs)
Operating system: Windows 10
Pixel resolution: 2560 x 1600

Comment: I asked about your computer because I started seeing exactly the same thing (not just with the Lecos plugin, but also a few others) when I upgraded my Windows computer to one where the monitor resolution is higher than 1920 X 1080 (HD).  From this, I suspected that the issue was related to the monitor resolution.  However, when I adjust the screen resolution using the Windows settings, the problem persists.  Sorry I don't have the answer, but I thought that I should include my experience.

Comment: Ah Stu, you pointed me in the right direction though, thank you! I closed QGIS, adjusted my resolution to 1920 x 1080 and changed size to 100% then reopened QGIS and the plugin and its much better. Not like it was on my previous device but I can now see and select all the cells / fields at least. Strange that it isn't working for you though!

Comment: Aha, I never thought to adjust the size to 100%, but that does help somewhat.  I suspect that the ultimate solution is for the plugin authors to update their code to account for hi-res monitors.

Comment: Ah glad that helped a little. Yes, agreed. I contacted the author of the Lecos plugin, but sadly he is no longer developing it further

Comment: That is unfortunate.